# Java - Print specific column values in jcombobox using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi, xls

I have a .xls file with only one sheet called "clients" and it contains data as it follows:

Name | Surname | Full name | Date of birth | City

I need to get all the values in the "Full name" column and I need to print them in a jComboBox.
Is there a way of doing that?
Thank you in advance

Comment: This question is too broad. What is your concrete question? You would need read the Excel sheet data using `apache poi` and get the data of third column into a data structure which then can be used to construct a `JComboBox`. A `Vector` would offer, as there is constructor  [public JComboBox(Vector<E> items)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox-java.util.Vector-).

Answer (score 1):

To read Excel files using Apache POI one needs creating a `Workbook` object from a Excel file. Then one chooses the needed sheet and iterates over the needed rows. Then one gets the cell values from the needed column.

See [Busy Developers' Guide to HSSF and XSSF Features](https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) for how to use Apache POI.

The simplest way to get the cell values is using `DataFormatter` of Apache POI. `DataFormatter.formatCellValue` gets the cell values as string in the same format as shown in Excel. Using current `apache poi 5.2.2`, `DataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells` can be set `true`. Then no formula evaluation is needed when cell values are formula results.

While iterating over the rows and getting cells one needs to know that totally empty rows are not stored in sheet's  data. So `Sheet.getRow` might return `null`. Also unused cells are not stored. So `Row.getCell` also might return `null`. That's why null-checks are necessary. And if empty cells shall not matter, `Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL` can be used in `Row.getCell`. Then empty cells also get returned as `null`.

The data could be stored in a data structure which then can be used to construct a `JComboBox`. A `Vector` would offer, as there is a constructor [public JComboBox(Vector items)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#JComboBox-java.util.Vector-).

Complete example:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import java.util.Vector; 
import javax.swing.*;

public class ReadExcelColumnToVector {
    
 private static final DataFormatter dataFormatter = new DataFormatter(java.util.Locale.US);
 private Workbook workbook; 
 
 public ReadExcelColumnToVector(String filePath) throws Exception {
  this.workbook = WorkbookFactory.create(new FileInputStream(filePath));
  this.dataFormatter.setUseCachedValuesForFormulaCells(true);
 }
        
 public Vector<String> getData(int sheetIndex, int firstRow, int dataCol) {
  Sheet sheet = this.workbook.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);   
  Vector<String> data  = new Vector<String>();
  String cellValue = "";
  for (int r = firstRow; r <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); r++) {
   Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
   if (row != null) {
    Cell cell = row.getCell(dataCol, Row.MissingCellPolicy.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
    if (cell != null) {
     cellValue = this.dataFormatter.formatCellValue(cell);
     data.add(cellValue);
    }
   }
  }
  return data;
 }
 
 public void closeWorkbook() {
  try {
   this.workbook.close();  
  } catch (Exception ex) {
   ex.printStackTrace();
  }      
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  
  //ReadExcelColumnToVector app = new ReadExcelColumnToVector("./ExcelExample.xlsx");   
  ReadExcelColumnToVector app = new ReadExcelColumnToVector("./ExcelExample.xls");   
  
  //get data from first sheet, starting on second row, third column
  Vector<String> data = app.getData(0, 1, 2); // all indexes ara 0-based
  
  app.closeWorkbook();
  
  System.out.println(data);
  // use Vector<String> data to construct a JComboBox
  JFrame frame = new JFrame("JComboBox Sample");
  frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  frame.setSize(500, 100);
  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  JComboBox<String> comboBox = new JComboBox<String>(data);
  panel.add(comboBox);
  frame.add(panel);
  frame.setVisible(true);
 
 }
}
```